# Error when trying to run an electron .deb file to my HDMI Port on Raspberry Pi Zero 2

Tags: server, xorg, raspberrypi, electron

I've built an electron app that I would like to deploy to a pi zero w2 and have it auto start when the device is plugged in. It should work similarly to a fire stick.

It will be plugged in to power and HDMI and the pi will boot directly into the application displaying it full screen kiosk mode.

I've gotten the app working well in development on my mac book and I used docker buildx to run an ARM build using electron-builder. That has given me a .deb file which I've successfully installed onto my Pi with minimal headache.

Now the problem I'm facing is that when I try to run the app I get the following error:

```
ozone_platform_x11.cc(240) Missing X server or $DISPLAY
```

I've just installed xinit and I've tested that I can get that basic version working with xterm but I'm stumped as to how I can get my built electron app to output to my HDMI port.

*Specs*

- Raspberry Pi Zero 2
- Ubuntu 23.10 server

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this?

### Update 1

I've also just tried XvFb and that results in the following errors

```
admin@raspberrypi:~$ DISPLAY=:99 menu-cast
[8825:1220/224041.367004:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(590)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop was not provided by any .service files
[8854:1220/224043.732757:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(320)] No suitable EGL configs found.
[8854:1220/224043.733590:ERROR:gl_context_egl.cc(140)] eglGetConfigAttrib failed with error EGL_BAD_CONFIG
[8854:1220/224043.735294:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(320)] No suitable EGL configs found.
[8854:1220/224043.735755:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1090)] eglCreatePbufferSurface failed with error EGL_BAD_CONFIG
[8854:1220/224043.736283:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(81)] gl::GLContext::CreateOffscreenGLSurface failed
[8854:1220/224043.736657:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(397)] Could not create surface for info collection.
[8854:1220/224043.742806:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(88)] CollectGraphicsInfo failed.
[8854:1220/224043.782362:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[8872:1220/224046.738974:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(128)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
```

I'm not sure if this puts me further from working or closer to it

### Update 2

Okay, I've made some headway here

- Run `xinit` leave the GUI with xterm in it running
- SSH into my pi
- Run `DISPLAY=:0 menu-cast`

Now I get the app running on top of my xterm GUI, it's not full screen yet but it's a good proof of concept that it can work.

I guess now the question is, how do I start the x11 server with only my app running in full screen?

Comment: 23.10 is the release I installed from the pi imager

Comment: So there was a lot of dependencies generated by the electron app. I believe that included x11,  but I also installed xinit and xserver-xorg. As I mentioned in my post, when I run `xinit` it does open xterm in a new GUI

Comment: Just added 2 updates, the second update has brought me closer to a working solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fix for me was the following...

1. Create an .sh script
   ~/gui.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
menu-cast
```

2. Run `xinit ~/gui.sh`

Not sure why it works when passing the command in shell script, but that's all it took for me.